# get backend var from php into reactjs via webpack

Tags: php, reactjs, webpack, react-router, backend

How can I get a php backend var into my reactjs (using react-router) via webpack.

I want to do something like:

```
<?php 
  if ($us->inGroup('Admin')) { ?>
    <script>
      var groups = true
    </script>
<?php 
  }
?>
```

Then use that `var groups` inside my reactjs app via webpack (inside the bundle.js)

Here, where my reactjs app is -> `<script type="application/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>`

Thank you.

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to do this? You have your `<script src="/bundle.js">` located **after** the `var groups = true` code, correct?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that when I do `console.log(groups)` it says `undefined`

Comment: Is that when the user (`us`) is not in the `Admin` group?

Comment: it happens all the time. How can I tell to webpack to get the value from groups var into the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Webpack to do this. You just need to make sure that the `groups` variable is in the global scope. In your `.php` file, set the `groups` value by using a ternary statement to echo `true` or `false` based on the value return from the `inGroup` call.

```
<script>
  var groups = <?php echo $us->inGroup('Admin') ? 'true' : 'false'?>;
</script>
```

Comment: I did it with `window.entry`. The question is: is it the best way? is it correct to use `window` to pass vars info?

Comment: You might want to read up on JavaScript variable scopes, but the gist is that if you set a variable in the global scope, it will be attached to the `window` object. You can then reference `window.yourVariableName` throughout your project.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there was a solution via webpack.

Comment: This was suggested to me, to use externals https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: That is useful if you have a library that you are importing in your application (either using `require` or `import`), but that you are loading via a method outside of the bundle (i.e., through a `<script>` tag). You do not need to do that for this because you are directly referencing the variable, not trying to import it.

Comment: I could do it by doing: `<script>
      var entry = {
        groups : false
      };
    </script>`, and adding the following to the `webpack.config.js` : `externals: {
    entry: 'entry'
  },` , and this in the file I wanted to use that var: `var entry = require("entry")`