# Webpack not parsing <%= %> syntax in HTML document

Tags: javascript, templates, webpack

Webpack not parsing `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.header %>` in HTML document.
In `<title>` tag I've used `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.header %>` variable but its printing it as a string i.e. "<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.header %>".

My webpack look like:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const generateHTMLPlugins = () =>
  glob.sync('./src/**/*.html').map(dir =>
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      filename: path.basename(dir), // Output
      template: dir, // Input
      title: 'HTML Wesdsdsdin',
      header: '<h1>hello world</h1>',
    }));

module.exports = {
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
  entry: [
    './src/js/app.js',
     './src/style/main.scss'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ....
    ],
  },
  plugins: [

    .....
    ...generateHTMLPlugins(),
  ],
  stats: {
    colors: true,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

Basically, I want to make header and footer partial components and inject it them using webpack. Please suggest me right path.

Comment: most likely because your webpack file is js and cannot parse php

Comment: might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449909/get-backend-var-from-php-into-reactjs-via-webpack